# Rails 2.3.8 app working on a computer and not in another (same code and db)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the computer that doesn't work it throws me the following error then I access the website:

```
Expected C:/path/to/app/app/helpers/admin/dashboard_helper.rb to define Admin::DashboardHelper
```

Do you know why is that? I don't think it's the code because I has never happened to me in my computer...

**Edit**

There's no much to show...

```
module Admin::DashboardHelper
end
```

**EDIT 2:**

This is what I get in the development.log after I access localhost:

```
Expected C:/Users/Triton/Documents/Brian/Proyectos/YouBlogg/app/helpers/admin/dashboard_helper.rb to define Admin::DashboardHelper
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:426:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:364:in `constantize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `constantize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb:137:in `helper'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb:115:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb:115:in `helper'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb:120:in `helper'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb:115:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/helpers.rb:115:in `helper'
C:/Users/Triton/Documents/Brian/Proyectos/YouBlogg/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `load_file'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:379:in `load_file'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `require_or_load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:425:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:89:in `dispatch'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:48:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:111
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
C:/Users/Triton/Documents/Brian/Proyectos/YouBlogg/script/server:3
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about showing the code form `dashboard_helper.rb` ?

Comment: I've edited the post to show you that..but I don't think the code is the problem...as it works fine on my pc, and this is the first time I'm running a Rails app in the second one, so I think it's something to do with some config...(the gems are not the problem because both pcs have the same)

Comment: Do the file permissions on both systems match exactly - esp. for each directory in path `app/helpers/admin` ?

Comment: Which file permissions should I check? I don't think if that's the problem.

Comment: Do you have a longer error message? What do your logs say?

Comment: I've edited the question with that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be HPricot gem that was missing...whay a clear error message it threw, ha!